# Filtering data based on a nested array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I have created a dynamic filter for table data, based on this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/magalhaespaulo/pen/jbYXPP?editors=1010).

The example only uses a simple array of objects, with no nested arrays.

My data needs to be filtered based on values that are nested in a child array, `serviceList`, like so:

```
var portfolio = [
  ApplicationNumber: "EP17345678"
  Stage: "Filing"
  id: 1
  serviceList: [
    currentStageColour: "Green"
    currentStageCostUSD: 12200.4
    serviceStatus: "Epct available" //status needed to filter
    serviceType: "Form1200" //status needed to filter
  ]
]
```

And further to the example located in the Codepen above, I have made amendments to the filter options and where the data is displayed, like so:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="cat in categories" class="filter-box" ng-init="filter[cat]={}">
    <h4 class="font-h4 m-b-sm">{{cat}}</h4>
    <div data-ng-repeat="value in getItems(cat, data)" class="checkbox-container">
        <label class="filter-container">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[cat][value]" ng-model="value"><span class="font-body">{{value}}</span>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<tr data-ng-repeat="patent in filtered=(data | filter:filterByPropertiesMatchingAND)">
```

I can post my own code if required but it is essentially the same provided in the Codepen (except of course the layout of the array).

***Question***

How do I create functionality to filter the table data based on the nested array values of `serviceStatus` or `serviceType`?